# No cycles engine in opensuse?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting, linux

I am using opensuse 13.1, and blnder 2.67b. In my blender there is no cycles renderer. I tried in the preference to enable it but it says that the cycles script is missing. How do i install the cycles render engine in opensuse??

Comment: Are you using a version downloaded from http://www.blender.org/download/ ?

Comment: no i am using the yast (the software manager ) version.
is the download version have cycles renderer??

Comment: i have downloaded and installed the blender 2.70a rpm.
but still no success.

Comment: Download from blender.org and not from repositories and see if the issue persists

Comment: Most likely it's because the version from the repositories is compiled without cycles. In case the portable versions from blender.org stop working because of different library versions, you can always [compile blender yourself](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender).

Comment: I think using standalone version is better option rather than compiling the source codes for beginner like me. Beside that some of the dependencies are not provided by manufacturer for Opensuse 13.1 64bit. And now i have blender 2.70 as software manager installed without cycles, blender 2.71 as extracted version with cycles working well. But thank you gandalf for your help. I have some blender files like landscape scene and 3d name logo created by myself for testing and I am new at blender and i am understanding the differences between blender internal and cycles engine.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah! That solved my problem, i downloaded the blender2.71.tar.gz2 version from blender.org and it have the cycles engine, though the tarball zip does not contain the installation. It have the self dependent blender package, just needed to be extracted. The site says the glibc2.11 is required, but my blender is working. i guess my os already have that. Thanx bro for helping me.