# Cycles not available in 2.77?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, installation

I can't select *cycles* as render engine. I have tried changing the user preferences as well as re-installing blender.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you mean by pop up? If you mean a small window that pops up when you press F12, that is under "render" setting properties, at the top of the panel, just under render/animation/audio buttons, there's a "display" list to select where the rendering should go, and one of the choices is "new window", which gives you a "pop up", in a sense...

Comment: possible duplicates: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/no-cycles-engine-in-opensuse, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47894/cycles-render-option-not-showing-up-in-blender-2-77/65040,

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't let you change it, or you don't even see it as an option? BTW 2.77 definitely lets you use cycles...

Comment: the option isint even there

Answer (score -1):

never mind I had to change blender render to cycle render

Comment: So the solution to absence of Cycles render in render engines list was to .. select Cycles from render engines list ? Strange.